# referencing a button on a parent form

Tags: getelementbyid

On my website...`form1` is the parent web page and has a disabled button (`button1`), a login button and an iframe. The login button sets the source of the `iframe` to a login form (`form2`) with a user id and password text boxes and an `ok` button. `Form2`'s ok button click sets the same `iframe` source to `form3` which evaluates the login and on success, enables the disabled button on `form1`.

Question: what is the javascript command in `form3` to enable the disabled button in form1?

neither

```
window.parent.getElementById("button1").disabled = false
```

or

```
window.document.form1.getElementById("button1").disabled = false
```

seem to enable the button.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The answer is:

window.top.document.getElementById('button1') or window.parent.document.getElementById('button1') if the parent document isn't the top document.